# good practice for testing mocked object

Tags: java, testing, mocking, coding-style

It is good practise to match mock objects widely but verify them precisely.
for example:

Using this:

```
when(myMock.has(any())).thenReturn(myValue);
```

Rather than:

```
when(myMock.has(eq("blah")).thenReturn(myValue);
```

Along with:

```
var result = myMethod();
assertThat(result, is(myValue));
```

Because it is making sure that it is always returned `myValue` regardless of the `has` method input.

There was a good explanation for this rule but I can not find it.
something along the lines: `match widely and verify precisely`.

It would be great if you can advise me about the name of the rule or some reference to it?

Comment: Actually both ways are correct. Everything is dependent on test case you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is quite simple: **It will make your live easier.**

Imagine the case that a caller will not call your method with "blah". In this case you rely on the mocking framework what will be returned, most likely null, zero or false. Your test will then run into a different direction or even fail with a NullpointerException. For other developers it will be hard to understand what went wrong here.

If you match widely, your test will continue as expected, but you should place a verification afterwards that makes the test fail with a clean reason. Developers tend to omit the verification step, wich renders the test useless quite often.
Usually there is no reason to match on a precise parameter value, except for the case when you want your mock to act differently on two values.

Most frameworks provide methods for the method call verification, e.g. Mockito:

```
@Mock
private Repository repository;

@Test
private void testReadData() {
    Mockito.when(repository.findById(any())).thenReturn(yourEntity);
    
    // run your test
    
    Mockito.verify(repository).findById("foo");
}
```